# 1800-ish SFX Library for film battle?

Tags: design

Hi Guys, I'm in need of authentic or whatever comes handy for a battle scene taking place in the early 1800...think 1820.

I'm talking about horses, long powder rifles explosions, cannons, men yelling and swords being hit.

Do you know any SFX Library or have access to that kind of sound materials? The ones I have access to sound kinda medieval to me...

Thanks in advance!

Olalo.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small (roughly edited) pile of 1800s-era rifles and cannons, close and distant perspective, plus a cannon on wheels rolling on a dirt path. Recorded at a Civil War re-enactment so there are some bits that have stray talking etc. on the tailoffs. Some of that may disappear into the din of a battle mix though--I used these sounds as the basis of an 8 min. battle scene a few years ago. This is just a few of them; there are more. It's an old recording but hopefully it will help.

[Civil war sounds](http://soundcloud.com/joe-griffin/civilwar-sounds) by [Joe Griffin: Sound Design](http://soundcloud.com/joe-griffin)

I also have some sword sounds recorded in-studio. I'll dig that out if you like and put together another sampler.

Comment: You're a life saver Mr...You should have a Badge named after you.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So hey, do you still need more stuff or are you set? Sessions got away from me this week.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got some stuff along those lines. How quickly do you need it?

Comment: We begin post-production in 4 weeks...

Comment: Can I get a glimpse of it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've been away. I will put together some samples for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 very nice libs from BOOM:

"Historical Firearms" - here is a link about how it was made (also as link to library itself):
http://boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94

and "Black Powder":
http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/black-powder